# Is there any message receiving limit per device on Azure IoTHub?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

Is there any message receiving limit per device on Azure IoTHub?
If any, can I remove or raise the upper limit without registering additional devices?

I tested 2 things to make sure if I can place enough load (ideally, 18000 message/s)on Azure IoT Hub in the future load tests.
① Send a certain amount of mqtt messages from a VM.
② Send a certain amount of mqtt messages from two VMs.

I expected that the traffic of ② would be twice as large as that of ①. But it wasn't. Maximum messages per minute on IoTHub of ② is not so different from that of ①. Both of them are around 3.6k [message/min]. At that time, I registered only one device on IoT Hub. So I added another device and tested ② again to see if the second device could increase the traffic. As a result, it increased the traffic and IoT Hub had bigger messages per minute.
Judging from this result, I thought IoTHub has some kind of limit on receiving message per device. But I am not sure. So if anyone know about the limit, could you tell me what kind of limit it is and how to raise the upper limit without registering additional devices because in production we use only one device.

For your information, I know there is a "unit" to increase the throughput in IoTHub. To increase the load I changed the number of unit from 2 to 20 in both ① and ②. However, it did not make messages/min in IotHub bigger. I'd also like to know why the "unit" did not work as expected.

Thank you for reading, in advance. Any comment would be my help.

Answer (score 1):

Every basic (B1,B2, B3)  or standard unit of IoT Hub SKU (S1, S2, S3) has specific daily message quota as per https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/iot-hub/. A single IoTHub can support 1 million devices and there is no per device cost associated, only the msg/day quota as above.

e.g. S1 SKU has 400,000 msg/day quota and you can add multiple units of S1 to increase capacity. S2 has 6000,000 msg/day and S3 has 300,000,000 msg/day quota per unit and more units can be added.

Before this limit is reached IoTHub will raise alert which can be used to automatically add more units or jump to higher SKU.

Regarding your test, there are specific throttling limits to avoid misuse of the service here -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling

As an example, for 18000 msg/sec you will need 3 units of S3 SKU (each with 6000 msg/sec rate limit). In addition there are other limits like how quickly connections can be attempted, if using Azure IoT SDK's the built-in retry logic helps overcome this otherwise you need to have retry policy.  Basically you dont want million device trying to connect at the same time, IoTHub will only accept connections at a certain rate. This is not concurrent connection limit but a rate at which new connnections are accepted.